# Removing words with special characters in them

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a long string composed of a number of different words.

I want to go through all of them, and if the word contains a special character or number (except '-'), or starts with a Capital letter, I want to delete it (the whole word not just that character). For all intents and purposes 'foreign' letters can count as special characters.

The obvious solution is to run a loop through each word (after splitting it) and then a loop through each character - but I'm hoping there's a faster way of doing it? Perhaps using Regex but I've almost no experience with it.

Thanks

ADDED:

(What I want for example:)

Input: "this Is an Example of 5 words in an input like-so from example.com"

Output: {this,an,of,words,in,an,input,like-so,from}

(What I've tried so far)

```
List<string> response = new List<string>();

string[] splitString = text.Split(' ');

foreach (string s in splitString)
{
    bool add = true;
    foreach (char c in s.ToCharArray())
    {
         if (!(c.Equals('-') || (Char.IsLetter(c) && Char.IsLower(c))))
         {
             add = false;
             break;
         }
         if (add)
         {
             response.Add(s);
         }
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

For me a word should be a number of characters (a..z) seperated by a space. ,/./!/... at the end shouldn't count for the 'special character' condition (which is really mostly just to remove urls or the like)

So:
"I saw a dog. It was black!"
should result in
{saw,a,dog,was,black}

Comment: Is that really necessary? I think my question is more than understandable.

Comment: We are not asking you to put your whole project in here. You said "I have a long string.." Put some part of that string where that words occur where you want that checking to happen. Then tell us this this `foo` word should be checked for `bar` condition and the resultant output should be `FooBar`

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal most programmers are able to translate a feature request ("literature") into code - there's nothing wrong with reading is there? Perhaps Aabela is thinking of a solution _before_ writing any code, which makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Aabela, define "word" please. Is `foo.` a word or a word followed by a period? Is `123`, `.` or `!#%&` a word (to be removed)?

Comment: Hmm, I would like it to be 'a word followed by a period', but I hadn't considered that issue - I'm just splitting them by spaces - but I really should fix . and , at the ends.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: I know that. I myself get stuck with it. But when such kind of question arises, most common comment comes "What have you tried?". That comment is question to OP so that he is not treating SO as rentacoder.com. Moreover if OP answers comment with some code, people at SO can get a sense of what OP wants or where he is wrong. If he is headed in wrong direction or is confused (that's why he is here asking about it) people having answer can help him. W.r.t. this question, b4 posting code he got -4 votes & a close request (Reason: Not a real Question) and now answers started pouring.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Agreed that the OP did not display any effort taken at first, I just found your initial comment a bit negative without any reason for negativity.

Comment: It worked for me. I tested it with a number of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

(?<=^|\s+)(?[a-z-]+)(?=$|\s+)

Edit: Meant `(?<=^|\s+)(?<word>[a-z\-]+)(?=(?:\.|,|!|\.\.\.)?(?:$|\s+))`

Rules:

1. Word can only be preceded by start of line or some number of whitespace characters
2. Word can only be followed by end of line or some number of whitespace characters (Edit supports words ending with periods, commas, exclamation points, and ellipses)
3. Word can only contain lower case (latin) letters and dashes

The named group containing each word is "word"

Comment: Using this and the explanation I was able to extend it to allow words which can be followed by punctuation marks as well. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  I had just realized about the punctation issue and came up with `(?<=^|\s+)(?[a-z-]+)(?=$|\s+|\.|,|!|\.\.\.)`.  Is that what you extended it to be?

Comment: @MarkM: That pattern would not compile. Aren't you missing something? I mean where's the ``named group`` in ``(?<=^|\s+)(?[a-z-]+)(?=$|\s+)`` or in ``(?<=^|\s+)(?[a-z-]+)(?=$|\s+|\.|,|!|\.\.\.)`` as you mentioned?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right - copy error.  I meant `(?<=^|\s+)(?<word>[a-z\-]+)(?=$|\s+|\.|,|!|\.\.\.)`.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Regex regex2 = new Regex ("(?<=\\s|^)[a-z-]+(?=\\s|$|\\.|,|!|;)");
MatchCollection r2 = regex2.Matches(text, 0);

That worked for me. (Still have minor issues like "www.example" being accepted but otherwise its giving me the right results.

Comment: Try this: `(?<=^|\s+)(?<word>[a-z\-]+)(?=(?:\.|,|!|\.\.\.)?(?:$|\s+))`.  It accepts words ending in ,/./!/... but requires that there is a trailing space or end of line.  That should take care of cases such as "www.example"

Answer (score 2):

So you want to find all "words" that only contain characters `a-z` or `-`, for words that are separated by spaces?

A regex like this will find such words:

```
(?<!\S)[a-z-]+(?!\S)
```

To also allow for words that end with single punctuation, you could use:

```
(?<!\S)[a-z-]+(?=[,.!?:;]?(?!\S))
```

## Example ([ideone](http://ideone.com/BA5hX)):

```
var re = @"(?<!\S)[a-z-]+(?=[,.!?:;]?(?!\S))";
var str = "this, Is an! Example of 5 words in an input like-so from example.com foo: bar?";

var m = Regex.Matches(str, re);

Console.WriteLine("Matched: ");
foreach (Match i in m)
    Console.Write(i + " ");
```

Notice the punctuation in the string.

Output:

```
Matched: 
this an of words in an input like-so from foo bar
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work very well. However it's filtering out words which finish with punctuation marks. Is it possible to modify that to not check the last character?

Comment: @Aabela, yes you can. Updated and also added an example.

Comment: *PS:* `(?!\S)` is just a shorter way of writing `(?=\s|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Microsoft's [How to: Search Strings Using Regular Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - it's about regexes in C#.

Comment: I took a look but the impression I'm getting is that I'll still need to loop one word at a time. Which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() {"asdf", "sdf-sd", "sdfsdf"};

for (int i = strings.Count-1; i > 0; i--)
{
   if (strings[i].Contains("-"))
   {
       strings.Remove(strings[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a starting point. right now it just checks only for "." as a special char. This outputs : "this  an  of  words in an  like-so from"

```
        string pattern = @"[A-Z]\w+|\w*[0-9]+\w*|\w*[\.]+\w*";
        string line = "this Is an Example of 5 words in an in3put like-so from example.com";

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern);
        line = r.Replace(line,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways, the white-list way and the black-list way. With a white-list you define the set of characters that you consider to be acceptable and with the black-list its the opposite.

Lets assume the white-list way and that you accept only characters `a-z`, `A-Z` and the `-` character. Additionally you have the rule that the first character of a word cannot be an upper case character.

With this you can do something like this:

```
string target = "This is a white-list example: (Foo, bar1)";

var matches = Regex.Matches(target, @"(?:\b)(?<Word>[a-z]{1}[a-zA-Z\-]*)(?:\b)");

string[] words = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", words));
```

Outputs:

```
// is, a, white-list, example
```

Comment: Would not work as intended with for example `example.com` (`example` and `com` would match) nor `123-fail` (`fail` would match).

Comment: Yep, this solution uses word boundaries instead of spaces. I posted this before reading the updates and since other answers addressed the updated question I did not bother to update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use look-aheads and look-behinds to do this.  Here's a regex that matches your example:

```
(?<=\s|^)[a-z-]+(?=\s|$)
```

The explanation is: match one or more alphabetic characters (lowercase only, plus hyphen), as long as what comes before the characters is whitespace (or the start of the string), and as long as what comes after is whitespace or the end of the string.

All you need to do now is plug that into `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, regexString)` to get your list of words.

Reference: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet